# check if a local user is locked out although he is logged in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to check if a user is using an account or locked out from a password protected account.

the command (query user) returns "active" even though the user is locked out.
and the process "explorer.exe" will still be active.

```
get-WmiObject win32_useraccount -Namespace "root/cimv2" | %{$_.lockout}
```

this also returns:
    "False"

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you're asking, but assuming you mean "Show me logged in users whose user accounts are locked", this should do it:

```
# Get locked local accounts
$lockedAccounts = @(Get-WmiObject win32_useraccount -filter "LockOut=True")

# Get login sessions including disconnected ones
# Get the username, ignore sessions with no username
# Username is in the form "computer\user" so remove "computer\"
$users = @(Get-TerminalSession | select -ExpandProperty UserName | ? {$_})
$users = @($users | % { (Split-String $_ -Separator "\")[1] })

ForEach ($account in $lockedAccounts) {
    if ($users -icontains $account.Name) {
        write "Locked Account $(account.Name) is logged in"
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it completely, but I've tested the bits of it separately and it looks likely to work.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The problem is that even if the account is locked out


    Get-WmiObject win32_useraccount -filter "LockOut=True")
will not return any users



I have managed to work around it using:
    

Get-EventLog -LogName Security | where {$_.instanceid -eq "4634"} | %{$_.TimeGenerated} | sort TimeOfDay -Descending | select TimeOfDay -First 1

Comment: @user3430337 I just tried it on my PC (Windows 7 SP1 x64), setting a two-attempt lockout threshold, creating a test account, trying to "runas" with the wrong password until it said the account is locked, then running `Get-WmiObject win32_useraccount -Filter "Lockout=True" |select -Property Name,Lockout |ft -AutoSize` and it showed the locked account OK. Are you sure you don't mean a disabled account rather than a locked one? If you run `Get-WmiObject win32_useraccount | select -Property Name,Disabled,Lockout` is WMI showing all your users and the states you expect?

Comment: I am using Win 8.1 Enterprise. It is still returning False. And No, I don't mean disabled accounts.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | where {$_.instanceid -eq "4634"} | %{$_.TimeGenerated} | sort TimeOfDay -Descending | select TimeOfDay -First 1
```

Comment: If you do go for this solution, it's slow to get everything in the event log, then send it all down the pipeline to filter and sort it. You can specify those things as part of the Get-EventLog command directly, and have it only return the events you care about, e.g. `Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4634 -Newest 1`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what this command does and how it solves the OP's problem?

Comment: @ScottGress the OP is the one who posted this answer to his own problem (I also don't see how the most recent logoff event helps).

Comment: yes thank you. I used this at the begining but the problem is that '-newest 1' will return nothing. Strangely instead '-newest 3' would return a record! I don't know if the number put after 'newest x' would ever need to be changed for the command to return a value?

Comment: @ScottGress I need to run a command on each login after lockouts which begin after a specific starting time ($x = (Get-date)) so that a command runs after each login from a lockout.

Comment: @user3430337 I've repeated the same tests on my Windows 8.1 Pro system; get locked out users, shows none. Created a test account and used runas to lock it out, get locked out users, shows the test account. Then tried Get-EventLog as I posted in my comment and that works as well and returns an entry. (and `-Newest 3` should return 3 records (or, up to 3)). I don't know what the difference is, but something sounds not right with your system.